# Can I use clutch friction plates for a Triumph Street Triple from 2012 for a Triumph Street Triple from 2015

Tags: motorcycle, clutch, triumph

I bought a used Triumph Street Triple from 2015 and suspect the clutch friction plates are worn down.

Before I open it up, I might as well buy the plates since they're not expensive and I found these [ones on ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/EBC-CK-Clutch-Friction-Plate-Set-Triumph-Street-Triple-07-12-26731815-CK1206-/331759710280?hash=item4d3e6b7048:g:9bgAAOSwUV9WoT6j&vxp=mtr#rwid) claiming to fit Street Triples from 2007-2012. My question is, did they change the clutch for the 2013 model or can I use the same ones?

Comment: I, like you, am not finding any clutch related parts listed for 2013+ ... I'm wondering if these have not hit the streets yet due to warranty replacement. You don't usually find aftermarket or replacement parts for vehicles of whatever type until warranties start expiring.

Comment: Seems premature. How many miles are on that clutch? What makes you suspicious the plates are worn? Have you ensured it is adjusted properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The 2015 is a reworked engine**

The 2015 Triumph Speed Triple engine is a bit different from the 2012.  Different cams, crank, connecting rods, pistons, etc.

The clutch plates in the 2015 are a bit larger in diameter.

The clutch plates you found may barely fit but I would not use them.   They are different part numbers.